# Web.config Builds? Should I be using SlowCheetah?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, slowcheetah, web-config-transform

I have a web api project and I want have different web.config build when I switch to say "release" and build.

In the past for window services I used on the app.config SlowCheetah and when I would build it would build whatever was selected in the dropdown(ie debug/release).

I read something that web.configs don't need slowCheeta but when I use the dropdown, change to release and look in the bin folder it is not using the release web.config.

How can I make this work?

Bonus would be if I could do it on debugging as well.

Comment: Correct, you do not need SlowCheetah for web.configs, they already have built in support. Unfortunately you cannot just switch environments and use that for local debugging, the config transforms get applied to the correct environment directory within the bin folder, but it then used for deployment, not local testing.

Comment: Hmm. I not sure why it does not work for me. I have in the web.config basically my dev connection string(to run on local debugging). I then have in my release config a new connection string yet it does not get replaced on build when "release is chosen" The preview xml transform is showing me it should work.